# Can I remove a label, richtextbox in c#? when a button is clicked?

Tags: c#

I have a dynamically created `Label`, `RichTextBox` via a button that is constructed via array.

```
Label dateLabel = new Label();
dateLabel.Text = dateArray[i];
dateLabel.Name = "date" + i;
dateLabel.Location = new Point(154, 5 + (50 * i));
dateLabel.Tag = dateLabel;
dateLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(91, 20);
panel1.Controls.Add(dateLabel);

RichTextBox placeTravelLabel = new RichTextBox();
placeTravelLabel.Text = placeTravelArray[i];
placeTravelLabel.Name = "placeTravel" + i;
placeTravelLabel.Location = new Point(272, 5 + (50 * i));
placeTravelLabel.Tag = placeTravelLabel;
placeTravelLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(148, 45);
placeTravelLabel.ReadOnly = true;
panel1.Controls.Add(placeTravelLabel);

Button clearButton = new Button();
clearButton.Name = "clearButton" + i;
clearButton.Text = "Remove";
clearButton.Location = new Point(1200, 5 + (30 * i));
clearButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.clearButton_Click);
panel1.Controls.Add(clearButton);
```

Now I want them to be `remove` something like this.

```
public void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dateLabel.Remove();
   placeTravelLabel.Remove();
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can call `Dispose` on the control or `Remove` it from the containing object (form, panel, etc).

Comment: The problem is the dynamically created textbox and label is in another click_event.

Comment: Then you'll need to find the control by looping through the containing control and identifying it somehow (name, tag, etc.)

Comment: Or creating a list of such controls that might need removing at some point so you have a reference to it later for removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Try

```
panel1.Controls.Remove(dateLabel);
panel1.Controls.Remove(placeTravelLabel);
```

You obviously need to hold the references to them when you create them (i.e. declare them as fields in your class) or mark them somehow (e.g. in `Tag` property) and enumerate `panel1.Controls` to find them later.

I think it should also be possible to use closure on local instances by defining button's click event as lambda to avoid declaring those controls as fields. I do **not** recommend this, as typical flow is more readable and straightforward. Having said that:

```
Label dateLabel = new Label();
//...
panel1.Controls.Add(dateLabel);

RichTextBox placeTravelLabel = new RichTextBox();
//...
panel1.Controls.Add(placeTravelLabel);

Button clearButton = new Button();
//...
clearButton.Click += new EventHandler((s, e) => 
    {
        panel1.Controls.Remove(dateLabel);
        panel1.Controls.Remove(placeTravelLabel);
    });
panel1.Controls.Add(clearButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo code built up with LinqPad but should give you enough to work with.

I assume that you are working WinForms as there is no tag to say if it is Winforms of WPF, but this is the code that you need that would remove the label for you.

```
var frm = new Form();

var lbl = new Label();
lbl.Name = "myLable"
frm.Controls.Add(lbl)

frm.Controls.Remove(lbl)
```

if you ignore the first two lines of the declarations, you simply need `FormName.Controls.Remove(LabelName)